# How to run SSH commands on remote system through java program (followup)

Tags: java, command-line, ssh, command

I am trying to run commands/executables in a remote host through a Java program. Here is the code I got from a related thread. I CAN connect to the remote host and read the stream through the **BufferedReader in**. However, I am NOT able to send/execute commands using **out.println("ls /home/ubuntu");**. Do you have any recommendations? I am working on a MAC OS system.

```
Process p = Runtime.exec("ssh myhost");
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream());
Thread.sleep(3000);
while (in.ready()) {
   String s = in.readLine();
   System.out.println(s);
}

out.println("ls /home/ubuntu");
Thread.sleep(3000);
while (in.ready()) {
    String s = in.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
}
out.println("exit");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had used a library [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), but I guess [sshxcute](http://code.google.com/p/sshxcute/) looks better as I went through the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Got it to work.

```
PrintStream out = new PrintStream(p.getOutputStream());
```

does not work for me so I changed it to this.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(p.getOutputStream())), true);
```